# Erase script tag text while script executing

Tags: javascript

I've encountered an `eval` polyfill that does something like that:

```
(script = document.createElement("script"), script.text = code, document.head.appendChild(script).parentNode.removeChild(script))
```

and inside the `code` variable the first line is:

```
document.currentScript.textContent = ""
```

how the hell does the script tag continue to executes when the script tag is actually empty? and for what purpose ?

Comment: Once the `<script>` content has been parsed by the JavaScript runtime, the source text doesn't really matter.

Comment: It continues to execute because the contents have already been loaded into memory, it no longer needs to read the contents of the script tag, as @Pointy said, once the JavaScript has been parsed by the relevant run time environment, the contents aka the source text is irrelevant.